# how to post data to web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sapui5

Problem Description:- i am trying to call web services of different domain(i.e. Systems are not connected locally with each other) so i am getting error:-"Failed to load https://sap.atlassian.net/: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

```
var username = "pra@sap.com";
        var password = "Sa8";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data1,
            url: 'https://sap.atlassian.net',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            ProcessData: true,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "accept, X-Custom-Header, x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type"
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: ```headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "accept, X-Custom-Header, x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type"
            }``` this is server-side headers. They mean web-service allows you to use it.

Comment: are you using SAP Web IDE?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might need to double-check URL. There must be some relative URL as well.

This is related to preflight. See https://www.gyanblog.com/gyan/39-explaining-issue-response-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check

Can you post detailed stacktrace?

PS: Its always bad practice of putting your username/password openly. You should immediately change your password!

Comment: also a bad practice for using `crossDomain` via `ajax`